# I need help to edit side margins in mobile view of a WordPress website

Tags: css, wordpress, styling

I need help to edit side margins in the mobile responsive view of a WordPress website.

[Page Example](https://resumesmag.com/a-survival-guide-for-handling-a-horrible-boss/).

This website is using the Market theme, when you open the website from a PC, it looks OK, but when you browse from a smart mobile, text margins (from left and right) are large and affecting the amount of viewable data on a smart mobile screen.

I want to remove these left and right margins (in a smart mobile view) without changing anything else.

previously I contacted the theme developers, and they gave me this code to use. But sadly, it didn't solve my problem.

Here is the css code:

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
.mk-posts .text .mk-text {
padding: 20px 20px 20px 0
}
.mk-posts {
padding: 60px 0;
}
}
```

Thank you!

Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following css code into the customizer of your WordPress installation.

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .mk-posts .text .mk-text {
    padding: 20px 0;
  }
  .mk-posts .text {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, Thank you for the code. Actually, it shifted text from the left side slightly, so it is better than before. But I wish to completely remove margins. It is life now on the website, you can check it. And if you have other suggestions, your help is appreciated!

Comment: Hi Tharwat, the text seems centered. You can inspect it with your browser dev tool. The 'container' class add 15px on each side and the 'mk-post' class adds 20px on each side.